# Why do physicists primarily study TMDCs when researching 2D materials, and not focus as much on many other 2D materials?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, material-science, electronic-band-theory, graphene

Why do physicists primarily study [transition metal dichalcogenide (TMDC) monolayers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_metal_dichalcogenide_monolayers) when researching 2D materials, and not focus as much on many other 2D materials?

Other 2D materials also have bandgaps depending on the layer, like TMDCs, and exhibit properties like topological phase. There are also other 2D materials containing transition metals that have strong Spin-Orbit Couplings. However, most papers currently published focus on research related to Graphene or TMDCs. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Please, do not use acronyms without explaining their meaning. Even if well known in some communities, they may be completely unknown in others.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes. The question is very clear, IMHO. The problem with the acronyms is settled, so can the voters please give some reason?